# Does a MySQL DISTINCT command work by storing distinct keys in memory?

Tags: mysql, database

I've tried looking through the [MySQL source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/5.7/sql), but found it very hard to locate where the function for DISTINCT is at.

**The problem:**
I've got a database with 57 million rows, which could get much bigger. It has a lot of rows with duplicates, and I want to sum the values of a column in those duplicate rows to have a table with the summed values but no duplicate rows.

I tried inserting into a new table using unique constraint, but the query ran for few hours and didn't complete. So we stopped it and a colleague tried with group by, and it ended up crashing MySQL.

**Solution we want to try:**
So we considered creating a table with no index and inserting into it, dummy rows of all distinct rows and then using upsert to update all those rows and thereby get the sum of the values. To do this, we need to know how DISTINCT actually works. If it keeps all distinct keys in memory, then we might encounter a MySQL crash again.

There are 3 columns, a combination of which makes a row distinct. If we use something like `INSERT INTO B SELECT DISTINCT * FROM A`, how will MySQL ensure distinctness? Does it keep a HashMap in memory of the column values or does it check the entire table B for duplicate values each time it inserts a row from table A?

EDIT:
Table schema:
`id, cellID, attributeID, entityID, value, comboString`
Here, id is the primary key and the combination of `cellID`, `attributeID` and `entityID` is unique. So the problem is that I have rows like:
1, **456**, **3**, **2**, 4.5, "4.5.6"
2, **456**, **3**, **2**, 75.3, "4.5.6"
3, 672, 4, 6, 78.3, "6.7.2"
4, 453, 4, 3, 3.6, "4.5.3"

And I need the consolidated table to be:

1, **456**, **3**, **2**, 79.8, "4.5.6"
2, 672, 4, 6, 78.3, "6.7.2"
3, 453, 4, 3, 3.6, "4.5.3"

The values 4.5 and 75.3 were added because 456, 3 and 2 were same in rows 1 and 2.

Comment: Try including all fields (including the values you want to sum) into an index. This completely alters the way queries work by bypassing the storage file and allowing the queries to rely completely on the index. Can't guarantee it will work but it may help.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I've edited my question with the table schema. As you'll see, the values are different, so won't creating an index on `value` be overkill in this case? As of now I just want to know the behaviour of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: As Mike already wrote, you should create an index for it. To answer your `distinct` question: it depends: if you don't have an index, it will create a temporary table first (in memory/temp space) and basically simulate an index. If you do have an index, it doesn't need to check for duplicates and usually doesn't need a temp table, as it can just give out the required values "on the fly" while reading the index from start to end. Also: since you do an upsert afterwards, you can do it in one step (using that index) and use `group by` (which is what `distinct` usually becomes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an actual new table (as you seem to imply), it might be way easier to forgo the 'clean' option in pure SQL, and just write a script in your favorite language.

in pseudocode:

```
line = read_line_from_databas()
if( not exists_in_new_table){
    create_row_in_new_table(line)
}else{
    add_values_to_existing_line_in_new_table(line)
}
```

This will not crash your database I assume, as they are all very simple, one-off queries. You just need to run your script long enough for it to finish.